# PHP read a cookie that is on another domain

Tags: php, cookies

I have two domains. One domain contains the login script. It creates a cookie when logged in. Another domain have a URL shortener.

So, on the 2nd domain that have the URL Shortener script have a file called session.php. Usually I was using `$_COOKIE['sessionid']` to get the session id and match it using database.

How can I get the session id now? I have tried few ways but none of them have solve my problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For obvious security reasons, you can't read a cookie that belongs to another domain.  You can do it across sub-domains though.

Why not append the session id to the forwarded URL?

Comment: What do you mean by 'append it to the URL'?

Comment: @pnm123: as part of the query string: `http://mysite.com/page.php?sid=A12638BCEF2733`

Comment: Is it necessary to check the session id against a database in the second application? Is it not sufficient to merely check for the existence of a token (created at successful login, destroyed on logout) stored in the first application's cookie?

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using a SSO implementation?

http://www.jasig.org/cas

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

We use it at work, it's awesome! It means we don't have to worry about these types of problems.

Comment: What kind off user database did you connect to CAS?

Answer (score 3):

[Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) are sent by the browser and only to the domain, the cookies were set for.

There is not much (meaning *nothing* ;) ) you can do.

But if your domains are two different subdomains (e.g. `login.yourdomain.com` and `shortener.yourdomain.com`) you just have to set the domain name accordingly to make the cookie valid for all subdomains.
In this case, it would be `.yourdomain.com`.

You might want to read the documentation of [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

---

Maybe it is better if you clearly describe what you want to accomplish. Probably there is another solution that does not involve cookies.

Comment: Isn't there any way to call it back. Like adding a file on 1st domain and call it from the 2nd domain?

Comment: @pnm123: What do you mean with *adding a file*?

Comment: “Not much” is not nothing. ;-)

Comment: @Felix Kling: like call_cookie.php. Actually, I have tried this. I mean using $_COOKIE['....'] on call_cookie.php and call it using file_get_contents() but it didn't work.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I am currently using .domain.com cookies all around my site.

Comment: behaviour of wildcard domains varies by browser - some (e.g. MSIE) let you pick your own policy

Comment: @symcbean: Maybe, I am only referring to the documentation: *To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com then you'd set it to '.example.com'. The . is not required but makes it compatible with more browsers.*

Answer (score 1):

Just while setting cookie from the login page 
set the cookie to entire domain like this

```
setcookie("c","value",time()*3600*24,"/");
```

in this way you can set cookie to your entire domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a cookie from the other domain.
though there are several ways to pass a session id. You can search SO for the `cross-domain authorization`

The easiest way is to pass a session id via query string

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Cookies are bound to a single domain. You can use cookies across multiple subdomains though.