# login to two websites at the same time in PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

how do I use the same web session that was created in one web app to another web app? In order words, if I login to site1.php, how do I automatically get logged in (without having to fill a form or anything) to site2.php using the same credentials that I used to login on site1.php?

Any help please

Comment: Do these sites share a common database, or at least a guarantee of the same user table (username and password)?

Comment: yes, both username and password come from the same table

Comment: Actually, not necessarily, the two web apps could be totally independent

Answer (score 1):

Your users propably get a cookie with their session id set If not, do so. Both sides would have to use the same session backend  to be able to get the session for the given id (from cookie). To share sessions between websites both sites need to use the same session handler. For example in a database.

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Storing-PHP-Sessions-in-a-Database/

Comment: Using a single cookie will only work if the two sites share a common domain (a.domain.com and domain.com for example).

Comment: But what if the two websites have two completely different domains? Doesn't a cookie belong to only one domain? How do I retrieve the cookie of domain1 from domain2?

Comment: You can not. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919968/php-read-a-cookie-that-is-on-another-domain

You could transfer the session id via the URL though. http://bla.com?PHPSESSID=1234567